# "X in Japan is different from [that/those] in other countries"

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, pronouns

I was wondering if the following sentence is clear:

> The book industry in Japan is very different from [that/those] in many other western countries.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct to use *that* there? Or should it be replaced by *those*, to agree with *western countries*?
2. In this sentence, is *that* (or *those*) taken to refer to "the book industry" or "the book industry in Japan"? because I kind of feel that it would be clearer if the sentence read

   > In Japan the book industry is very different from [that/those] in many other western countries.

   But I am not quite sure, because to me as a non-native English speaker the two sentences mean the same thing. Which one is better, which is more precise for academic writing?

Comment: BTW As Japan is not a Western country, you shouldn't refer to "other" Western countries, and Western should be capitalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different from *that of* many other countries.

*that* is correct, *those* is plural and could work here since you are referring to a number of countries. The comparison you are making is *the book industry in Japan* vs the rest of the world.